# Do commands continue running after I close my ssh session?

Tags: ssh

For example, I ssh into a server and run a command say ... wget, then I close the terminial window. Do my download continue? Or does it depend on the app? If so how do I know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends.

If you're closing a SSH session, you're logged out and all active programs are killed. This might become problematic if you've frequent connection drops and therefore it's recommended to use the [`screen`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70614/427545) program in a SSH session if you do not want to loose your session on exit.

Most programs are gone after a closed SSH connection if they're run on the command line, e.g. `nano` or `apt-get`. `do-release-upgrade` also uses `screen` and won't be interrupted by a connection drop.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use nohup if screen isn't available.  Check the wikipedia entry on it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup and you'll find a couple of examples.